# operation on column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in SQL database, where one column contains the character "C" or "P". 
I want to define a new column, where the value is 1, if this character is "C" and zero otherwise.

kind regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 3):

if you want to define through projection, try

```
SELECT columnName, IF(columnName = 'C', 1, 0) newValue
FROM tableName
```

As an alternative suggested by `Michael Berkowski`,

```
SELECT columnName, (columnName = 'C') newValue
FROM tableName
```

Comment: Or if you're going MySQL-specific just `(columnName = 'C')`, resulting in 1 or 0

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I absolutely agree, but i showed it that way just for clarity `:D`. anyway i will update it.

Comment: How the above statement creates new column with respective transformed values of the old column? I just need an explanation.

Comment: @sємsєм this doesn't create new column on the table but only by projection through `SELECT`. the question says `define a new column` which is incomplete. there are many ways how to understand that phrase that's why in my answer i said `define through projection`.

Comment: @JW. So could I understand that, I have to create the new column by any mean, phpmyadmin for example, and then running your query?!

Comment: @sємsєм The only thing you need for this query to work is the column *columnName*, they are using an `IF` to return 0 or 1 based on the value in *columnName*

Comment: @sємsєм is `define` the same with `create`?

Comment: @sємsєм that is my interpretation. if you have a better answer than this, why don't you write an answer for it?

Comment: @JW. Indeed, I don't know a better or worth answer, I just discuss to know the answer and ensuring that I understood it well. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    your_fields,
    IF(your_column = 'C', 1, 0) AS new_field
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want it to be a permanent column? If so, create a new column in your table with a default value of 0. Then issue an update statement as follows:

```
UPDATE tableName SET newColumn = 1 WHERE oldColumn = 'C';
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually creates a new column.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER MY_TABLE ADD NEW_COLUMN INT
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET NEW_COLUMN=1 WHERE OTHER_COLUMN='C'
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET NEW_COLUMN=0 WHERE OTHER_COLUMN='P'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT
WHEN Col_name1='c' THEN
INTO your_Table (Col_name2)
VALUES (1)
WHEN Col_name1='P' THEN
INTO your_table (Col_name2)
VALUES (0);
SELECT * FROM your_Table;
```

It will work.

Comment: :D I  forgot that was for Mysql. Above insert is for Oracle